# Error while installing SonarQube TFS 2017 extension

Tags: sonarqube

I have TFS 2017 U1 running on premise and am trying to install the SonarQube extension v3.0.2. During the install I'm getting a weird error stating that a task definition with the same id already exists. 
Already checked if this extension is already installed but it's not there.

Any ideas how to debug this issue further?

Comment: Do you have the same issue, when trying to install that plugin on a fresh installation of SonarQube? (Freshly unzipped SonarQube, Empty database, default sonar.properties) Which version of SonarQube and the scanner do you use? Could you please add the exact log messages to the question (so that it can be easier found with google)?

Comment: @Matthias Läßig I tested as my side, everything works correctly. Have you ever installed the extension before(any version)? Please double check the installed extension, if exists, just  remove the previous version then install the new version. If you can not find it in the installed extension, just try to clean caches for both of your TFS client and App tier server, also for browsers.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT: SonarQube and TFS are a fresh install, the git repo has been imported into TFS and a CI build created. Nothing fancy.
I'm not sure, if I did a previous install of the extension. But I can't see it under manage extensions to uninstall. But it's listed under browse local extensions - how can I remove it from that list?

After cleaning the caches I still get the same errors. BTW tfx lists no build task definition with the GUID from the error, but I can still see the [DEPRECATED] sonarqube build steps. Even tried to remove them via tfx with no result (and no error).

Answer (score 0):

> "But it's listed under browse local extensions"

In `local extensions`, it will list all the installed extensions for all collections.  That means you have installed the extension before, but maybe for another collection. Please make sure you have installed it for your current collection, otherwise you cannot see the extension under the `manager` tab to Disable or Uninstall it.

However, you should see the extension in **Manage Extensions** page, you can navigate to the page by this link : `http://server:8080/tfs/_gallery/manage`

You will find the extension, right click on the extension then **Remove** it.

Now you can upload the new version or install it directly from marketplace.

If you also can not find the extension under Manage Extensions page, just please refer to this similar thread for further troubleshoot : [Error when installing extension](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85070/error-when-installing-extension.html?childToView=88298#comment-88298)

---

**UPDATE:**

As Matthias mentioned in below comments, the end up solution is deleting and recreating my Team Collection, then install the extension.

[image]

Comment: I found it under /_gallery/manage and was able to uninstall. But trying to reinstall from the marketplace gave me the same error.

Comment: @MatthiasLäßig Make sure you have really removed it from TFS, please double check that. If still repro, try clean the caches for your browser, or try with another client machine. Or, you can download the extension then upload to TFS  instead of install from marketplace directly.

Comment: in the end I had to delete and recreate my Team Collection